# Vue UI: "This relative module was not found"

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I have used Vue before with Laravel, and now I am getting started with Vue CLI.  I have installed Vue CLI and used Vue UI to create my first project.  It pre-installs the Hello World example, but when I go to Task > Build, I get the following error:

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./src/main.js in multi ./src/main.js
```

Why is this?  I can see the file there, and as far as I can see I have not made any config choices or changes that would cause this problem.

I tried removing the node_modules directory and running `npm install`, but that did not seem to help.

When I was installing Vue CLI I ran into an error because I am on macOS Catalina, but I googled it and installed some Xcode tools and that seemed to sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

I created a second project and the Hello World example works fine there.  I noticed that, as part of the process - in the terminal screen - it installed some additional plugins.  So perhaps that is what was missing from the first project.

The first project still does not compile, but I am happy to delete it and work with the second.